# How to search Google News by custom date range

Tags: google-news

I would like to search for news articles on Google about the topic **Puerto Rico** in the date range **04-01-2015** to **05-01-2015**.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

In the news search box at the far right hand side there is a down arrow. Clicking this will show advanced search features.

[image]

1. Type "Puerto Rico" into the box labeled "this exact phrase".
2. Set the "Date added:" drop down to "specified dates".
3. enter the begin and end date into the two date fields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative.

1. [Search](https://news.google.com/) for "[Puerto Rico](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=Puerto%20Rico)"
   [image: search for 'Puerto Rico']
2. Click "Search tools"
3. Click "Recent"
   [image: Search tools - Recent]
4. Click "Custom Range"
5. Put in your date range and click "Go"
   [image: custom range selector]

Answer (score 0):

Jason's is cool, but I think this way is faster. Make sure to follow the steps in order

[image: googlesearch]

Comment: You're searching the web index, not Google News.